# removing left shift count >= width of type warning

Tags: c

Why does this code generates a warning :

```
niko: snippets $ cat leftshift.c 
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    uint32_t var1;
    uint32_t var2;

    var1=55;
    var2=var1 << (sizeof(uint32_t)-8);

    printf("%d\n",var2);
}
niko: snippets $ gcc -g -Wl,--warn-common -ffunction-sections -fshort-enums -fdata-sections -Wall -Wextra -Wunreachable-code -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wunused -Winline -Wstrict-prototypes -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wformat  -D_GNU_SOURCE -fshort-enums -std=c99  -c leftshift.c 
leftshift.c: In function ‘main’:
leftshift.c:10:12: warning: left shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
  var2=var1 << (sizeof(uint32_t)-8);
            ^
niko: snippets $
```

While this same code does not:

```
niko: snippets $ cat leftshift.c 
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    uint32_t var1;
    uint32_t var2;

    var1=55;
    var2=var1 << (32-8);

    printf("%d\n",var2);
}
niko: snippets $ gcc -g -Wl,--warn-common -ffunction-sections -fshort-enums -fdata-sections -Wall -Wextra -Wunreachable-code -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wunused -Winline -Wstrict-prototypes -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wformat  -D_GNU_SOURCE -fshort-enums -std=c99  -c leftshift.c 
niko: snippets $
```

Is there something wrong with GCC ? Because size of uint32_t is 32 bits or isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sizeof returns the size in bytes. You should try this:

```
printf("%d\n", sizeof(uint32_t));
```

You'll probably find that it's 4, not 32. If you want the size in bits, you can multiply by 8: `sizeof(uint32_t) * 8`

Comment: Note that `%d` is incorrect type specifier for `size_t` that `sizeof` returns. Use `%zu` instead, or cast the argument to type that matches the type specifier.

Comment: `sizeof(uint32_t) * CHAR_BIT` is more portable and self-documenting.  OTOH `CHAR_BIT == 8` is very common.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof(uint32_t)` is 4 in your system, so the first code gets the right operand as (4-8) which is a negative number, hence the warning.

In the second code it is a positive number, so no warning.

Comment: `sizeof(uint32_t)` is type `size_t` so `sizeof(uint32_t)-8` results in a very large unsigned number.  That is why "left shift count **>=** width of type"

Comment: The right side of a bitwise operator is an additive-expression (6.5.7 of c11). It can be negative, but if it is negative the result is undefined. So, integer promotions will occur on sizeof(uint32_t) and it will become signed int and the result will be signed int. The result of the shift expression will be undefined.

Comment: If `sizeof(size_t) < sizeof(int)`, then the result of subtraction will be negative signed integer. If `sizeof(size_t) >= sizeof(int)`, then result is large unsigned integer. Either way, result is outside of allowed range of right bitshift operand (0 .. 31), and behaviour is undefined.

Comment: @user694733   The result of `sizeof(size_t) - sizeof(int)` is type `size_t`.  `size_t` is some unsigned type, not a signed integer.  The result cannot be negative.

Comment: @chux That is not what I said. There is no substraction `sizeof(size_t) - sizeof(int)`. Only subtraction `sizeof(uint32_t)-8` which has types `size_t - int`. If we are on a machine where `sizeof(size_t) < sizeof(int)` then result of `sizeof(uint32_t)` is promoted to `int` before subtraction, and substraction result can then be negative. Now considering the error message the OP got, this is *not* such machine, but such system can still exist.

Comment: @user694733 Agree with your analysis.  Now to find an example where `sizeof(size_t) < sizeof(int)`, a 32-bit processor with 64k memory?

Comment: in the example given in OP's question we are performing sizeof(uint32_t) -8. From the information in the question, we can guess that sizeof(uint32_t) is 4 and when we do 4-8 we get -4. (a signed number) as sizeof(uint32_t) will become signed int due to integer promotions.